# Java - Unable to Detect Files

Tags: java

Following on from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369892/java-perform-function-on-newly-generated-files-within-directory), my program doesn't detect the 300 images that have just been created in a particular directory; instead, it only detects `desktop.ini`, which is not the case as I can physically see that the files have been created within said directory and do exist.

Can somebody please explain why this happens as when I run the program the next time, it seems to work just fine?

The only way that something is detected within the directory on the first run is when there is at least one file which exists in the directory before the program is compiled and executed.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE:** Files are detected as follows:

```
//Default greyscale image directory (to convert from greyscale to binary).
static File dirGrey = new File("test_images\\Greyscale");
//Array of greyscale image filenames. 
static File imgListGrey[] = dirGrey.listFiles();
```

Comment: Not here, nor in your original question, have you described how exactly you're "detecting" files. How are you implementing the pseudocode "For all images within new directory" loop? Show the code.

Comment: Well, the code you added probably shows your problem. As you're creating the file list in a `static` array, it's created when the class containing the array is loaded by the Java class loader, which is probably *before* you create the image files.

Comment: @Joonas Thank you!  I moved the file list into the method itself and it worked. If you post your comment as a direct response, I will select it as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the file list in a `static` array, and it's created when the class containing the array is loaded by the Java class loader, which is probably before you create the image files. That's why the array contains an outdated list.

`static` is rarely needed, mostly useful for constants (things that never change, such as 42), for pure functions (`Math.sqrt()`) and a few other special cases. When you use it, you have to learn all the tricky initialization order stuff. Otherwise, just stick with non-static variables.

Answer (score 2):

without knowing how you create the images, this question is akin to 'How many kittens are under my desk right now?'

Are you creating the files yourself?  If so, are you closing any file handles referring to those files once they are created?

Comment: My previous question explains all of this in some detail.  However, I read in all [image] files within a particular directory, have them converted to greyscale and saved to another [empty] directory, and then this is where the problem lies; the newly-generated images are not detected unless I either a) run the program a second time, or b) have at least one [image] file in the directory before running for the first time (in which case, only the pre-existing images are detected).

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to know why `desktop.ini` is detected in the 'empty' directory...?

Comment: I think the question is worded incorrectly.  It's the *code that you wrote*, in Java, that is not meeting your requirements.  Your question makes it sound like the JDK is in error.  Without seeing your code, I'm betting that's not the case.  You'll make progress faster if you start assuming that your code and understanding about how Java should act are the problem.

Comment: If `desktop.ini` is detected in a directory, then this directory is not empty. So your question makes no sense. Just because you have beginners settings in your explorer (i.e. "Don't show ohhh so dangerous system files.") and don't see anything doesn't mean it's empty.